# Do I need the same 'using' declarations in a derived class as its base? (c#)

Tags: c#, monogame

Suppose I am using XNA or monospace. If base class uses XNA.Framework, like so:

```
using System;
using XNA.Framework;
class Base
{
}
```

Do(es) the inheriting class(es) implicitly use those declarations, or do I need to add using XNA.Framework for each one?

Comment: You should read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/12/referencing-assemblies-and-importing.html).

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need the same 'using' declarations in a derived class as its base?

No. Using statements are only there as a convivence to you so you don't have to write the fully qualified type name each time. That's its only purpose (ignoring allies and static).

Any type that is exposed in some way from your base class (method parameter, method return type, property type, etc) will always be the fully qualified type name.

For example, this:

```
using System.IO;
class Foo
{
    public File GetFile() { ... }
}
```

means exactly the same as

```
class Foo
{
    public System.IO.File GetFile() { ... }
}
```

<sub>*assuming that there are no conflicting "File" types in your project*</sub>

Your derived class *may* add using statements to reduce the length of the type name, if you wish.

Derived classes don't "inherit" any of the using statements from another file, as using statements are applied at the code file level, not the class/type level.